# Displaying the output of update query into shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sql-update, sqlplus

I am trying to display the result of an update statement "5 rows inserted" on my shell script.

One way i could figure out is

```
Declare count number;

Begin

Update tablename set colname="k";
count=sql%rowcount;
Dbms.out.put_line(count);
Commit;

End
```

The sql plus count variable is getting the value but i am unable to use it in my shell script.

I have to copy the value of sql plus variable into a shell script variable .but dont know how to do it.

Please help , also let me know if there is any other way to do it .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have `SQL*Plus` exit with with the value you want.  Here's an example (run this as a UNIX script):

```
sqlplus my_username/my_password@my_database << EOF
variable count number;

begin
  update mtl_system_items  -- your update goes here!
  set last_update_date = last_update_date
  where rownum <= 5;

  :count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:count);
  ROLLBACK;
END;
/


EXIT :COUNT;
EOF

echo Return code was $?
```

That is, when you `EXIT :COUNT` from SQL*Plus, the value of your `COUNT` variable will be accessible in `$?` in your UNIX script.  You'll need to save it off immediately into another variable, since `$?` will get overwritten if you run any other commands in your script.

Comment: hi Mathew,  Thanks for the solution, but the value of $? is not getting stored in a variable . when I am printing the variable it is showing blank value.

Comment: Seriously?  You pasted the above into a UNIX script, ran it, and it didn't print "Return code was 5" ?  What UNIX are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a variable assignment in a spool file and then reading that back in your shell script. For example:

```
sqlplus -s apps/apps@vis <<EOF
set feedback off lines 150 pages 0 head off termout off serveroutput on size 10000 echo off
variable count number;

begin
  -- Emulation of update that updates 40000 rows
  :count := 40000;
end;
/

spool outvars.sh
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('COUNT=' || :count);
end;
/
spool off

exit
EOF

. outvars.sh
echo "Back in shell, COUNT=$COUNT"
```

will result in this output:

```
COUNT=40000
Back in shell, COUNT=40000
```

Although slightly more indirect it has the advantage of being able to pass multiple values with a pretty arbitrary content, not just a single number limited to a small integer range.